# Reset Command line, paths, and so on

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina

I am running Mac Catalina 10.15.7.

I have installed a host of things like Anaconda, Homebrew and I simply can't install or import packages in Jupyter Notebooks. I have searched All over and tried any nuber of fixes involving .zsharc file, echo "path/stuff", changing paths, bins... At this point I don't know what is what and I simply can't install/ use packages. I want to start over. How can I reset things, uninstall everything I've installed set the paths back to factory?f

Comment: what error are you facing ? If you dont understand how it works when u installed it, you will find it difficult to uninstall them too. One easy way is create another admin user and then delete the existing one. Be careful while doing this incase you lock yourself out.

Comment: I install packages the modules aren't found in Jupyter. also I pip 20.x.x throws "distribution was not found and is required by the application". I can't find a clear fix for this either